# MCMC not constraining parameters correctly

Tags: bayesian, estimation, sampling, inference, markov-chain-montecarlo

I have to fit a model to some data and I was wondering how to interpret the results I get from the Bayesian parameter inference performed using emcee.
Model #1 has 3 parameters: $h_0,\Omega_m,\Omega_{\Lambda}$.The mathematical expression is (note that $d_H=\dfrac{c}{100h_0}$ and $\Omega_{\Lambda} = \Omega_{de}$):
[image]
Model # 2 has 4 parameters: $h_0,\Omega_m,\Omega_{\Lambda}, w_0$, with a similar expression:
[image]

These are the contour plots for the two models. You can see that in the 4-parameter case things get messy, and the posterior shape is far from being Gaussian for the last 2 parameters. Things don't improve tweaking priors, sample size, number of walkers.
[image: model 1] [image: model 2]
However, if I impose the constraint $\Omega_m = 1-\Omega_{\Lambda}$, thereby reducing the number of parameters by 1 for both models, thigs work nicely also for model # 2:
[image]

Now, the question is: **is it correct to conclude that the data are not "strong" enough to constraint both $\Omega_{\Lambda}$ and $w_0$?** or is there simply something wrong with the code? I'm using flat broad priors and a Gaussian Likelihood.
Thank you!